# I am having trouble with using getline

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with my code not reading the whole string name.

I have tried using `getline(cin, movieName)` as well as `cin.ignore()`, but I can't get it to work properly.

I am taking a beginner's course to this class, but my professor does not answer their emails.

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <iomanip>
     #include <string>

     using namespace std;

     int main()
     {

    string movieName;
    const float adultTicketPrice = 12;
    const float childTicketPrice = 6;
    const float percentTheaterKeeps = .20;
    int adultTicketsSold, childTicketsSold;
    float grossProfit, netProfit, amountPaidToDistributor;

    getline(cin, movieName);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);


    cout << "What movie played tonight?\t    ";
    cin >> movieName;
    cout << "How many adult tickets were sold?   ";
    cin >> adultTicketsSold;
    cout << "How many child tickets were sold?   ";
    cin >> childTicketsSold;


    grossProfit = adultTicketPrice * adultTicketsSold + childTicketPrice * childTicketsSold;

    netProfit = grossProfit * percentTheaterKeeps;

    amountPaidToDistributor = grossProfit - netProfit;


    cout << setw(10) << left << "Movie Name";
    cout << setw(23) << right << movieName << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Adult Tickets Sold";
    cout << setw(16) << right << adultTicketsSold << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Child tickets sold";
    cout << setw(16) << right << childTicketsSold << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Gross Box Office Profit";
    cout << setw(11) << right << grossProfit << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Net Box Office Profit";
    cout << setw(13) << right << netProfit << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Amount Paid to distributor";
    cout << setw(8) << right << amountPaidToDistributor << endl << endl;

    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't in fact call `getline`, so it's unclear how it demonstrates your "trouble with using `getline`". Show the code you are actually having trouble with. Also, what do you mean by "not working properly" - what's the input, what outcome do you expect, what do you observe instead? Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: Why do people having trouble with code not post the code they are having trouble with? It's bizarre. Please edit the code above to show how you are trying to use `getline`.

Comment: It has been edited to show the getline

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `std::getline(std::cin, movieName)` when you want to get input for `movieName`.

Presumably you're seeing a blank line when you start your program, and pressing `enter`. This sets `movieName` to `'\n'`. Remove that line, and switch `std::cin >> movieName;` with `std::getline(std::cin, movieName)`. (Remove the `std::`s if you're using a using declaration)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it